# Error in Converting double to BigInteger

Tags: c#, double, limit, biginteger

While solving a euler's problem ,I came across this..

`BigInteger temp = (BigInteger)Math.Pow(99, 95);
  Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString());`

It outputs the following number.
`3848960788934848488282452569509484590776195611314554049114673132510910096787679715604422673797115451807631980373077374162416714994207463122539142978709403811688831410945323915071533162168320`

But when I tried to find the power using this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=99%5E95) it shows..

`3848960788934848611927795802824596789608451156087366034658627953530148126008534258032267383768627487094610968554286692697374726725853195657679460590239636893953692985541958490801973870359499`

The **two values are different**. My question is there a **limit** on finding powers using **Math** functions or Is the **conversion** from double to BignInteger is wrong?

Comment: You have rounding issues due to double precision

Comment: @AlexH Thanks ..Solved it using BigInteger.Pow().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `BigInteger.Pow`, not `Math.Pow`.

With `Math.Pow`, the returned value is a double-precision floating point type whose precision is equivalent to roughly 15-17 significant decimal figures. Therefore only the first 15-17 figures will be correct.